# Custom helper not working in laravel, it return undefined function in controller

Tags: php, laravel

**Edit For those who may bump into this thread with similar error**
Remove the namespace from the helpers.php file as it is not a class.

In my own case, the correct code should be

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Session;




function showTest(){
    return "test";
}
```

**..and not**

```
namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Session;




function showTest(){
    return "test";
}
```

**Original Question**

I am looking to write a global function in laravel using the helper.

Here is my code
helpers.php

```
namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Session;




function showTest(){
    return "test";
}
```

Composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },

        "files":[
            "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
```

But when i call the function in the controller it returns error;

```
dd(showTest());
```

it returns this error;

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\User\showTest()
```

What could be the problem?

Also I have ran composer dump-autoload

**Modified**

I have tried all solutions posted here but it’s not working.

Php 8
Laravel 9

Comment: You need the full namespace

Comment: @aynber I have included the complete name space or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I should have expanded. You need the full namespace when you call the function, so `App\Helpers\showTest()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing this is to register your Helper files in Laravel's service container.

You could either do this in an existing service provider file, or create a new one, for example **HelperServiceProvider.php** (can be done with **php artisan make:provider**)

In the register method of the service provider, you can take your helper file and require them globally, as such

```
public function register()
{
    require_once(glob(app_path().'/Helpers/helpers.php');
}
```

If you have multiple files, you can simply put them in a for each

```
public function register()
{
    foreach (glob(app_path().'/Helpers/*.php') as $filename){
        require_once($filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Following this method, I got this error

`Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\User\showTest2()`

I want to die dump ShowTest2() in my controller.

Do I need to include anything else in the controller where I want to call it?

Answer (score 2):

First I want to apologize for all the troubles.

The problem was that I used namespace in my helpers.php file

This thread saved me

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29736097/14940381

Answer (score 1):

You need to run composer `dump-autoload` and it will work.

For more details [click here](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers)

Comment: I have done this severally before posting this question as stated.

Comment: @Here2Learn Make sure it's `dump-autoload`, not `auto-dump`

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. I did dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

Try loading them inside AppServiceProvider boot method instead of composer file.

```
require_once app_path('Helpers/helpers.php');
```

Comment: Return the same error

Answer (score 0):

composer.json

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
       "App\\": "app/",
       "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
       "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
   },

   "files":[
       "app/Helpers/helpers.php",
      "app\\Helpers\\helpers.php",
   ]
},
```

hepler.php

```
<?php

if(!function_exists('showTest')){
    function showTest()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}

if(!function_exists('showTest2')){
    function showTest2()
    {
        return "test 2";
    }
}
```

And run `composer dump-autoload`